# How to mock inherited method using JMockit

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

Below is my code and I am writting Junit test case for method perform. I want method getList to return dummy values as DB is not available. Please suggest how I can do the same using JMockit.

```
class BaseClass {

  public List<> getList() {
      return DataBase.getList();       
  }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

  public boolean perform(String temp) {
     boolean bool=true;
     List list = getList();
     for(String str:list){
           if(str.equals(temp);
               bool=false;
           break;
     }
     return bool;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not longer using JMockit  and switched to Mockito. Using @Mock annotation above issue can be resolved.

Comment: You mean the `@Spy` annotation, probably. But the JMockit test is simpler anyway.

Comment: @user1520277 -- If you don't care for your question any longer, and you don't mark any of the answers as helpful, could you delete it rather than leave it unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

It's not `BaseClass#getList()` that should be mocked, but `DataBase#getList()`:

```
public class ExampleTest {
    @Tested ChildClass cut;

    @Test
    public void findItemInList(@Mocked DataBase db) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Abc", "test", "def");
        new Expectations() {{ DataBase.getList(); result = list; }};

        boolean itemNotFound = cut.perform("test");

        assertFalse(itemNotFound);
    }
}
```

Mocking `BaseClass#getList()` would require *partial* mocking, which can be done with `new Expectations(cut) {{ cut.getList(); result = list; }}`. But partial mocking is a known bad testing practice that should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `ChildClass` does not overwrite `BaseClass::getList()` you have to mock `BaseClass::getList()`:

```
new MockUp<BaseClass>() {
    @Mock
    List<> getList() {
        return new ArrayList(); // your mock here
    }
 }
```